# Creating Typescript Module, Dependent Module Looking For Import In Local Folder; Module not Found Can't Resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

I've created and published a Typescript package. When I try to import a dependent module, instead of looking in `node_modules`, it looks for it in the current folder, and of course fails to find it. This happens when I install the module from npm in a new project and try to build it.

I'm using Node 18.18

Error:
`./node_modules/@namespace/module/dist/esm/odata2ts.config.js:1:0-54 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@odata2ts/odata2ts' in 'D:\Dev\Angular Test\my-app\node_modules\@namespace\module\dist\esm'`

The module is installed in `node_modules` as expected, I'm unclear why it wouldn't look in the usual location. No other dev dependency seems to be doing this.

This is the file throwing the error, which is being compiled from a .ts file in the main package's build phase before being published.

odata2ts.config.js:

```
import { EmitModes, Modes } from '@odata2ts/odata2ts';
const config = {
    mode: Modes.all,
    emitMode: EmitModes.ts,
    services: {
        namespace: {
            sourceUrl: 'https://some.url',
            source: 'src/resource/namespace.xml',
            output: 'src/build/namespace',
            prettier: true,
        },
    },
};
export default config;
```

My package.json for the published module:

```
{
  "name": "@namespace/module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/cjs/src/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/src/index.js",
  "umd:main": "dist/umd/src/index.js",
  "types": "dist/types/src/index.d.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "husky install",
    "prepublishOnly": "pinst --disable",
    "postpublish": "pinst --enable",
    "gen-odata": "odata2ts",
    "build": "npm run gen-odata && npm run build:cjs && npm run build:esm && npm run build:umd && npm run build:types",
    "build:cjs": "node tools/cleanup cjs && tsc -p config/tsconfig.cjs.json",
    "build:esm": "node tools/cleanup esm && tsc -p config/tsconfig.esm.json",
    "build:umd": "node tools/cleanup umd && webpack --config config/webpack.config.js",
    "build:types": "node tools/cleanup types && tsc -p config/tsconfig.types.json",
    "clean": "node tools/cleanup",
    "package": "npm run build && npm pack",
    "test": "jest --no-cache --runInBand",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage --no-cache --runInBand",
    "addscope": "node tools/packagejson name @namespace/module"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:namespace/module.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^13.1.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^13.1.0",
    "@odata2ts/odata2ts": "^0.31.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "pinst": "^2.1.6",
    "prettier": "^2.4.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@odata2ts/http-client-fetch": "^0.6.2",
    "@odata2ts/odata-service": "^0.17.1"
  }
}
```

And for the local application:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@namespace/module": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

If any other information is needed, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that @odata2ts was a devDependency and needed to be a dependency instead.